# Getting DOMParser object as Undefined IE 11

Tags: javascript

I have a xmlquery string which I am parsing using DOMParser in javascript.

Its's working fine with IE-11 in few domains however its failing in few and getting the error as:

> DOMParser is undefined.

Application is deployed in weblogic cluster. One thing what I have noticed is that if I access the individual node URL it works fine however using the public URL it fails. Really not getting any idea what could be the root cause here.

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: Posting some code sure would be helpful when you have a native method that works in some scripts, and not in others, in the same browser.

Comment: Could this be to do with IE security settings? Maybe your IE uses stricter settings that restrict DOMParser when browsing "public" sites.

Comment: The code which is failing is- var parser = new DOMParser();

Comment: I haven't set any custom IE security settings. Do you have any idea which setting which can restrict DOMParser.